# Reviewing without a trace

Tags: discussion, review

I just wanted to remark on something which happens more and more often since the new review system was deployed.

Some poor guy posts a non-answer, which gets into the review queue. Then people review it and feel compelled to leave a comment, and this guy that just wanted to say "thank you" but didn't know about commenting, gets a stream of comments telling him (or her) not to do that.

Moreover the boilerplate comments are quite formal and having a stream of formal sounding comments about your misbehavior is not a good feeling. Especially when you just wanted to say thanks.

> **Please** see if someone else left a comment before leaving one yourself. The review options include "don't leave a comment", which is more than reasonable if someone else did so already.

Comment: Could you point out an example? I'm not really sure what you are referring to here.

Comment: @MJD: Well, a 10k example: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/282325/622 and I saw more.

Comment: [There should not be more than one /review comment, duplication is prevented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143680/151385). Are you sure this is still happening, as it then would be a bug in the mechanism.

Comment: @MadScientist: Is that true for all sort of comments, or just one from each kind (and zero for "no comment")?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not sure how it works exactly